# Append component using jquery Angular +2

Tags: angular

Is it possible in Angular +2 to do this?

```
export class AppComponent {

    loadSomething()
    {
        $(.container).append('<app-test></app-test>');
    }
}
```

If it not, what is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to load component dynamically is to use `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ViewContainerRef`

```
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    private  loadSomething()() {
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AppTestComponent);
        const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
        ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

- `ComponentFactoryResolver` — service used to get the factory of the component we want to inject
- `ViewContainerRef` — the container of the parent of our component.
  createComponent(factory) is the part that actually injects our component into the viewContainerRef that calls it
- `ref` — Reference of the component we just injected. We call detectChanges on it so angular will call the necessary lifecycle hooks and start the change detection mechanism.

Check out following link for demo

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oosubv?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Great! but can I send a specific data from `load()` to home component?

Comment: For example if in home.html I have ngFor that reading data[], can I send other data from component to other and append it?

Comment: @MarvinEricson : let me give it a try :)

Comment: @MarvinEricson: Yes you can pass data check out this [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxd8fn?embed=1&file=app/helloworld/helloworld.component.ts)